# How to handle critical failures when using ignite cluster?

Tags: java, ignite

I want to use the ignite cluster in the production environment(ver 2.6). But I found that some critical failures will happen when I run these code as follow:

```
CacheConfiguration<Long, User> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("QQ");
cacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, String.class);
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
cacheCfg.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
IgniteCache<Long, User> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

And all the node in the cluster will crush. Here's the exception:

```
[22:00:12,240][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][CacheAffinitySharedManager] Failed to initialize cache. Will try to rollback cache start routine. [cacheName=QQ]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Cannot enable read-through (loader or store is not provided) for cache: QQ
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.validate(GridCacheProcessor.java:501)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:1439)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheStart(GridCacheProcessor.java:1945)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheAffinitySharedManager.onCacheChangeRequest(CacheAffinitySharedManager.java:791)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.onCacheChangeRequest(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:987)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:646)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2419)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[22:00:12,258][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Failed to reinitialize local partitions (preloading will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], discoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=DynamicCacheChangeBatch [id=cb8ca50a761-71740993-a932-4d4f-8576-767a180422e4, reqs=[DynamicCacheChangeRequest [cacheName=QQ, hasCfg=true, nodeId=edcdfc7d-e80a-4e1c-8c95-df649ecf3f64, clientStartOnly=false, stop=false, destroy=false, disabledAfterStartfalse]], exchangeActions=ExchangeActions [startCaches=[QQ], stopCaches=null, startGrps=[QQ], stopGrps=[], resetParts=null, stateChangeRequest=null], startCaches=false], affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=edcdfc7d-e80a-4e1c-8c95-df649ecf3f64, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.138.32.93, 10.202.235.150, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.117.1, 192.168.137.1, 192.168.56.1, 192.168.99.1, 2001:0:dcfa:40e1:18f9:17ae:f575:dfa2], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.138.32.93:0, /2001:0:dcfa:40e1:18f9:17ae:f575:dfa2:0, /192.168.117.1:0, /192.168.137.1:0, /192.168.56.1:0, /192.168.99.1:0, /10.202.235.150:0], discPort=0, order=6, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1544583579289, loc=false, ver=2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc, isClient=true], topVer=6, nodeId8=0c16ea29, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1544583612234]], nodeId=edcdfc7d, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheGroupContext.singleCacheContext(CacheGroupContext.java:385)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLocalPartition.<init>(GridDhtLocalPartition.java:198)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.getOrCreatePartition(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:812)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.initPartitions(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:368)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.beforeExchange(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:543)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.distributedExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:712)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2419)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[22:00:12,263][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Failed to wait for completion of partition map exchange (preloading will not start): GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [firstDiscoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=null, affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=edcdfc7d-e80a-4e1c-8c95-df649ecf3f64, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.138.32.93, 10.202.235.150, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.117.1, 192.168.137.1, 192.168.56.1, 192.168.99.1, 2001:0:dcfa:40e1:18f9:17ae:f575:dfa2], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.138.32.93:0, /2001:0:dcfa:40e1:18f9:17ae:f575:dfa2:0, /192.168.117.1:0, /192.168.137.1:0, /192.168.56.1:0, /192.168.99.1:0, /10.202.235.150:0], discPort=0, order=6, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1544583579289, loc=false, ver=2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc, isClient=true], topVer=6, nodeId8=0c16ea29, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1544583612234]], crd=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=0c16ea29-7560-43b5-960c-519ddf762374, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 10.202.60.170, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1], sockAddrs=[ignite-1.novalocal/10.202.60.170:10001, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:10001, /127.0.0.1:10001, /172.17.0.1:10001], discPort=10001, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1544583612245, loc=true, ver=2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc, isClient=false], exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], discoEvt=DiscoveryCustomEvent [customMsg=null, affTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], super=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=edcdfc7d-e80a-4e1c-8c95-df649ecf3f64, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.138.32.93, 10.202.235.150, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.117.1, 192.168.137.1, 192.168.56.1, 192.168.99.1, 2001:0:dcfa:40e1:18f9:17ae:f575:dfa2], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.138.32.93:0, /2001:0:dcfa:40e1:18f9:17ae:f575:dfa2:0, /192.168.117.1:0, /192.168.137.1:0, /192.168.56.1:0, /192.168.99.1:0, /10.202.235.150:0], discPort=0, order=6, intOrder=5, lastExchangeTime=1544583579289, loc=false, ver=2.6.0#20180710-sha1:669feacc, isClient=true], topVer=6, nodeId8=0c16ea29, msg=null, type=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT, tstamp=1544583612234]], nodeId=edcdfc7d, evt=DISCOVERY_CUSTOM_EVT], added=true, initFut=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=false, hash=533779784], init=false, lastVer=null, partReleaseFut=PartitionReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[ExplicitLockReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[]], AtomicUpdateReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[]], DataStreamerReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[]], LocalTxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[]], AllTxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[RemoteTxReleaseFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=3], futures=[]]]]]], exchActions=null, affChangeMsg=null, initTs=1544583612234, centralizedAff=false, forceAffReassignment=false, changeGlobalStateE=null, done=true, state=CRD, evtLatch=0, remaining=[8541a9eb-2c29-4e68-8c6c-0be8271d43b3, c4eb0a79-5ba4-4eba-80ea-6b0e1dc25853], super=GridFutureAdapter [ignoreInterrupts=false, state=DONE, res=java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0, hash=1173308534]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7307)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:207)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:159)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2433)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheGroupContext.singleCacheContext(CacheGroupContext.java:385)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLocalPartition.<init>(GridDhtLocalPartition.java:198)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.getOrCreatePartition(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:812)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.initPartitions(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:368)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.beforeExchange(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:543)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.distributedExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:712)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2419)
    ... 3 more
[22:00:22] Topology snapshot [ver=7, servers=3, clients=0, CPUs=24, offheap=9.3GB, heap=3.0GB]
[22:00:22]   ^-- Node [id=0C16EA29-7560-43B5-960C-519DDF762374, clusterState=ACTIVE]
[22:00:22] Data Regions Configured:
[22:00:22]   ^-- default [initSize=256.0 MiB, maxSize=3.1 GiB, persistenceEnabled=false]
[22:00:22,359][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=class o.a.i.failure.StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler, failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0]]
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheGroupContext.singleCacheContext(CacheGroupContext.java:385)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLocalPartition.<init>(GridDhtLocalPartition.java:198)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.getOrCreatePartition(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:812)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.rebalancePartition(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:2178)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.afterExchange(GridDhtPartitionTopologyImpl.java:698)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2488)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:2299)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[22:00:22,360][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#43][] JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0]]
```

All the nodes in the cluster crushed after, and all the cache and data lost.I try other failure handler listed in  https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling , and I found that `RestartProcessFailureHandler` will also still cause data lose, and the `NoOpFailureHandler` will cause the node to not accept subsequent requests.

So how to handle critical failures when using ignite cluster in the production env?

Comment: I guess you can write your own handler by extending `AbstractFailureHandler`.

Comment: Yes, it may be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration for Ignite cache creation is wrong. Check cache configuration properly. Refer this link
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-configuration

below configuration you can used if you need to stored data in cache only

```
CacheConfiguration<Long, User> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>("QQ");
cacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
IgniteCache<Long, User> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

If you want to store data in 3rd party database then you can use following configuration. Refer link https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store

```
cacheCfg.setReadThrough(true);
cacheCfg.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(CacheStore.class));
```

Where CacheStore is user define class which have the instruction for 3rd party data operation

Comment: I knew that the config is configuration, but what I meant to say is that how to handle this error. Since I want to use ignite in the production environment, if anyone write code like this, the cluster will crush and the other people will lose their data. It's hard to confirm that all the people will do the right thing.

Comment: Is it the complete configurations you have given in your question? If it is then this configuration should not work even in local environment. Because whenever you set setReadThrough or setWriteThrough property true then it is necessary to add its CacheStoreFactory.